# Running the same detection model on different GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, nvidia

I recently ran in to a bit of a glitch where my detection model running on two different GPUs (a Quadro RTX4000 and RTX A4000) on two different systems utilize the GPU differently.
The model uses only 0.2% of GPU on the Quadro system and uses anywhere from 50 to 70% on the A4000 machine. I am curious about why this is happening. The rest of the hardware on both the machines are the same.

Additional information:  The model uses a 3D convolution and is built on tensorflow.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. Try `tf.test.is_gpu_available()`

Comment: @stanley-zheng I tried `tf.test.is_gpu_available(0)` on both the machines. It returns true for both. The CUDA toolkit graphics drivers are installed correctly and are operational.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `Quadro RTX4000` does not use GPU.

The method `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` is deprecated and can still return `True` although the GPU is not used.

The correct way to verify the usage of the GPU availability + usage is to check the output of the snippet:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

On the Quadro machine you should also run (in terminal):

```
watch -n 1 nvidia-smi
```

to see real-time the amount of GPU memory used.

Comment: I checked on the powershell, nvidia-smi reports 7.2/8.0 GB is being used i total. but does not report that the python interpreter is using it.